smart contract code tracking
Good afternoon. I want to make the smart contract code publicly available, how to track patterns of parts of the bytecode, and so that when they appear somewhere I know about it. what tools do I need to use for this? and how hard is it to do
I apologize if I formulated something wrong
thank you in advance for your answer

I'm not aware of any services to search for partial bytecode pieces from contracts. I doubt such exists.
In theory, you can scan all available contracts for bytecode patterns (you either need some service that provides these or sync your own node from block 0 and gather the data), and monitor newly deployed ones. Not a trivial thing to do, but not impossible either...
But in general, it sounds like a bit weird request. Most contracts are open source and most code is available for anyone to copy. That's part of the ethos and helps a lot in driving innovation around here.

Perhaps I formulated it incorrectly. look how it was. My friend wanted to create his own token, he created a smart contract, added liquidity to the pair and so that no one would frontrun it, he made a seller fee of 99 so that, as I understand it, bots would not interfere. He bought himself $11 worth of tokens and retired from business. He comes in half an hour later and sees that someone minted 3 billion tokens and sold them to the pool,  here is the smart contract
0xa277e4De13ad467F0aE10F69d78926404eb41A41

so I’m wondering how the one who did this found out that my friend took his code and created a coin?

Sounds like your friend does not understand how tokens or DEXes do not work and this is not a real question. My recommendation is open new question about the actual problem and then have actual details on the question.
